# What is the difference between next-buff-tab & next-window-tab in SlickEdit

Tags: slickedit

> [update July 2016] This no longer applies, `next-window-tab` does not
>   exist in newwer versions such as SlickEdit 2014 v19.0.1.1.

Slick edit has two related commands, `next-buff-tab` & `next-window-tab`. (These can be executed by pressing Esc and entering at the command line, or by binding keys to them in options.) Is there a difference between them, and if so, what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of slicked are you using?

next-window-tab isn't available for me in 2014 slick edit and I don't see that in the later documentation I was able to find.  The closest match is next-window, which actually behaves like "Previous Tab" like command.  The next-buf-tab circulates on the active group tabs.  If you have multiple groups in multiple windows, the next-buf-tab, will not circulate through those other groups.

All that said, next-window seems to behave in way that I don't expect it to.

Comment: Hmm, I've updated to 2014 (v19.0.1.1 64-bit)
and indeed `next-window-tab` is no longer there.